# Embed editable google calendar for those who have the access

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api

When i try to embed the calendar i get the `<iframe>` tag which print only the read-only calendar even if i have the edit access.

Do i need to add any additional parameter in the `<iframe>` to make this enable?

Answer (score 5):

[I don't think it's possible to have an embedded calendar that is editable.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/umRw-44B-aQ)

However, you *can* use the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) to incorporate buttons or other functionality on the side that can edit the calendar. You can also  share the calendar as appropriate and users can then go to [Calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/) to make edits, which will then show on the embedded calendar.